# Is PVC ventilation duct safe for health in long term?

Tags: hvac, pvc

Some contractor says PP is safer (the arguments is it is used in food packaging...) and PVC will degrade and release toxic materials after 10+ years. But in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyvinyl_chloride there is no such thing.

Is PVC safe to be used as air duct in home for a long time like decades?

(Only health safety is considered, fire safety etc is not considered)

Comment: Some say swallowed saliva is a cause of death! It takes decades but prove them wrong every one that swallows saliva dies so it is 100% fatal!

Comment: @EdBeal That answer sort of answer this question. But the difference is this question is about air duct. Although something safe for water will commonly be safe for gas, but that is still not for sure right? You can only be sure after you have data about the same setup.